# Is it possible to align asset performance by trading session in python?

Tags: python, finance, trading, bloomberg

I have time series data in one minute intervals for the last 7 business days and I want to calculate and plot the cumulative change by trading session like this:

[image: BTC returns by trading session]

The 23-Jun 'Asia' trading session overlaps two days (i.e. 23:00 on 22-Jun > 07:00 on 23-Jun) and **I am unable to align the cumulative change calculation to take into account the 23:00 > 23:59 portion of the trading session** which falls in the prior day.

My code:

```
cl1 = con.bdib('CO1 Comdty', start_datetime=start, 
         end_datetime=end, event_type='TRADE', interval=interval)

cl1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(cl1.index)
cl1['Time'] = cl1['Timestamp'].dt.time

def bin_f(x):
    if x.time() < datetime.time(7):
        return 'Asia'
    elif x.time() < datetime.time(14):
        return 'Europe'
    elif x.time() < datetime.time(22):
        return 'US'
    else:
        return 'Open'

cl1['Timezone'] = cl1['Timestamp'].apply(bin_f)

perf = cl1[['close', 'Timezone']]
perf['Count'] = 1

perf['Minute'] = perf.groupby([perf.index.date, 'Timezone'])['Count'].cumsum()
perf['Session'] = perf.index.date

perf = perf.pivot(index=['Session', 'Minute'], columns='Timezone', values='close')

perf = perf[['Asia', 'Europe', 'US']]

perf = perf.diff()

perf = perf.cumsum()
```

Result

[image: Result]

Raw Data

[image: Raw Data]

Desired output:

Two new columns: `TimeZone` and `Session`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xbbg` to download intraday prices and use `pd.concat([...], axis=1)` directly to align the time series. Because the price data from `xbbg` carries timezone info and `pandas` deals with alignment automatically.

Comment: This is nice, the only caveat is that concat will work if the dataframes are aligned on times (not sure if xbbg guarantees that there will be no missing values/skipped rows if e.g. stock is halted).

Comment: it returns an empty DataFrame if halted

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if the trading of a stock is halted during the day (e.g. due to some significant news development).

Comment: those rows will be skipped - this is handled by Bloomberg automatically

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't think it answers the question. The 'Time' column is already aligned. I want to classify the TradingSession using the 'Time' column. For example, if the 'Time' is between 23:00 and 07:00 then TradingSession = 'Asia' or if the 'Time is between 07:00 and 14:00 then TradingSession = 'Europe' etc.

Comment: Trading hours are overlapped within these markets. One column won't be sufficient to distinguish them. `data.loc[~data[ticker, 'close']].isna()]` is the trading hours for given ticker.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to split the problem into two parts:

- convert all times to the same timezone using [`dt.tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html);
- merge on the nearest key using [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The data is already in the same timezone. I want to classify the timezone by geography. For example, if the 'Time' is between 23:00 and 07:00 then TradingSession = 'Asia' or if the 'Time is between 07:00 and 14:00 then TradingSession = 'Europe' etc.